# Improving view performance without using an Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to improve the performance of a view. Unfortunately I can't use an index since I'm using "Top Percent" and randomness in my query.

Here is the query used by the view

```
Select Top (10) Percent from Table
Order By NEWID()
```

The view pulls the data in around 50 seconds which is too much. I hope you could help me to find a solution for that, without touching the business layer.

Comment: Why are you ordering by NEWID()? If this is to generate the randomness I would suggest another approach, one in the business layer not at the database.

Comment: for random data selection

Comment: I wish I could do that, but I can't do that on the business due to the requirements of the system. Also the application was build more than 10 years ago.

Comment: How big is the table?  Do you have any other filters or does it just pick 10 percent of the records from the entire table?

Comment: The table got around 8 Million records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to improve this given your requirements. Get more hardware - only solution. It is likely you overload tempdb - in which case a high performance SSD and proper configuration on that one may help.

The reason is that in order to get the top 10 percent by your random order, SQL Server MUST process ALL rows, and order them by the random element.

This is the type of query that looks nice on paper but can lead to tremendous performance issues. I would start by looking at this requirement and try to get around it. FULL randomness is just expensive for non trivial data sets.

Answer (score 1):

For a truly random sample, you need some form of randomness.  One method that doesn't require sorting is approximate, but might be sufficient for your purposes:

```
Select t.*
from Table t
where rand(checksum(newid()) <= 0.1;
```

This is approximate, of course.  If you really needed *exactly* 10 percent, this approach would need more work.

An alternative if an almost-random-sample is good enough is `tablesample` (which you can read about [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx)).

```
select t.*
from table t
tablesample (10 percent);
```

Note that this does a random sample of *pages*, so it is not a true random sample.  And, it cannot be used in a view.

Comment: Tablesample can not be used in views

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table has ids. You can generate random numbers to pick the ten results in your business logic. From here your SQL would be:

```
SELECT percent FROM table
WHERE ID IN ([coma separated list here]).
```